# Rails with typeahead.js - 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, search, elasticsearch, typeahead.js

I'm in the process of putting together autocomplete for my search input using the Searchkick gem and typeahead.js. Following the gem's [tutorial](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#autocomplete) I've managed to get my model, controller, and routes setup as directed:

**Restaurant Model**

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchkick text_start: [:name], autocomplete: [:name], suggest: [:name]

  def search_data
    { name: name }
  end
end
```

**Search Controller**

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:query].present?
      @restaurants = Restaurant.search(params[:query], suggest: true)
    else
      @restaurants = []
    end
  end

  def autocomplete
    render json: Restaurant.search(params[:query], autocomplete: true, limit: 10).map(&:name)
  end
end
```

**Routes**

```
resources :search, :only => [:index] do
  member do
    get :autocomplete
  end
end
```

**Search Partial**

```
<%= form_tag search_index_path, method: :get do |f| %>
    <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], id: "autocomplete" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

I have a feeling that it's the JS that's giving me trouble. I'm loosely following the [docs](https://github.com/yourabi/twitter-typeahead-rails) on the gem's page and some SO posts and this is what I ended up with:

```
$(function() {
  var restaurants = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('restaurant'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: { "url":"/search/autocomplete?query=%QUERY" }
  });

  restaurants.initialize();

  $('#autocomplete').typeahead(null, {
    displayKey: 'name',
    source: numbers.ttAdapter()
  });
});
```

Notice the line:

```
remote: { "url":"/search/autocomplete?query=%QUERY" }
```

Back into the view, once I start typing in my input box I get this error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/search/autocomplete?query=%QUERY 400 (Bad Request)
```

Additionally I get this error in my console:

```
ERROR bad URI `/search/autocomplete?query=%QUERY'.
```

The `QUERY` is not getting interpolated. How do I fix this?

Comment: You are getting the bad URI because your route is invalid. You should use `collection` instead of `member`. The `member` will generate a path that looks like `/search/:id/autocomplete`

Comment: @AbM Is there anything additional I need to do because it's still giving me that same error after changing `member` to `collection`.

Comment: If it helps, this is how the route is being interpreted: `autocomplete_search_index GET  /search/autocomplete(.:format)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var restaurants = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('restaurant'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: { 
        url: "/search/autocomplete?query=%QUERY",
        wildcard: "%QUERY"
    }
});
```

- https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1219

Also you might want to fix your controller so it returns an empty ActiveRecord::Relation object instead of an empty array.

```
def index
   if params[:query].present?
     @restaurants = Restaurant.search(params[:query], suggest: true)
   end
   @restaurants ||= Restaurant.none
end
```

See http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/none